# Moving label to fit according to length vb.net

Tags: vb.net, label

Hi I have a button which will add a string in to a label. (this can be done multiple times.) As the user can add multiple strings with each one been a different length, is there anyway I can get it to find the length of the label and those around it so that it spaces out correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Label.Width will return the current width of the label control, but it sounds like you already know this.  Since the label can be narrower than the text it is trying to display, you would need to measure the full text using the graphics object.  This method will return the width of the text in a label:

```
Private Function getFullTextWidth(lbl As Label)
    Using g As Graphics = Label1.CreateGraphics()
        Return g.MeasureText(Label1.Text, Label1.Font).Width
    End Using
End Function
```

Alternatively, you could just set the label's `AutoSize` property to true, and then just check the label's `Width` property after you set the `Text`.